# What does 'ap' stand for in C examples?

Tags: c, coding-style

For example, in the reference:

```
type va_arg (va_list ap, type)
```

Does `ap` stand for argument pointer? Something else?

Comment: It actually stands for "author [is] phossilized". Justifiable in code from the 1970's or before, but much harder to justify today.

Comment: `Does ap stand for argument pointer?` could be. It's just a variable name, so it could stand for just about anything the author named it after.

Comment: Good one.   Thanks for the style suggestion.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Are you saying we shouldn't use variable arguments in modern c?

Comment: @this Is that *really* what was inferred? :|

Comment: @user2864740 Don't take everything seriously. Old people have firm beliefs :)

Comment: @this: I was thinking more along the lines of using names that the reader can understand a little more easily.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Oh , ok.  I `<3` va_arg

Comment: What color are we painting the Bike Shed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's actually an easy question to answer.

`ap` stands for *argument pointer*.

From [The C Programming Language](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/), Second Edition, Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie:

> 7.3 Variable-length Argument Lists
>
> [...] The type va_list is used to declare a variable that will refer to each argument in turn; in minprintf, this variable is called ap, for "argument pointer"

Comment: Good find! Chances are, Dennis Ritchie was the one who named that variable.

Comment: Good catch. It's still important to note that `va_list` is not necessarily a pointer type; it's a "pointer" only in an abstract sense.

Answer (score 6):

`ap` stands for *Argument Pointer*. In fact, it is [sometimes abbreviated as `arg_ptr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb57fad8.aspx):

```
type va_arg(
   va_list arg_ptr,
   type 
);
```

> - `type` - Type of argument to be retrieved.
> - `arg_ptr` - Pointer to the list of arguments.

Comment: Perhaps, but there's no support for that in the C standard or in the [ANSI C Rationale](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/d8.html#4-8). Both just use the name `ap` without explanation. It's also worth noting that `va_list` is *not* (necessarily) a pointer type.

Comment: @KeithThompson there is support in K&R2, see my answer

Comment: @KeithThompson Re: "both just use the name `ap` without explanation": same here. Good to know that user ouah found an answer.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>That's actually a difficult question to answer.</strike>

See [ouah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24345372/827263); the phrase "argument pointer" is mentioned in K&R2.

The `<stdarg.h>` header was introduced by the ANSI C standard in 1989. The [ANSI C Rationale](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/d8.html#4-8) doesn't show any examples, and doesn't use the name `ap` or `arg_ptr`. The standard itself (the latest draft is [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) uses the name `ap` in examples, but doesn't explain it.

I haven't been able to find an explanation of the name `ap`. It's plausible that it originally stood for "argument pointer", but it's also important to note that the type `va_list` is not (necessarily) a pointer type. In gcc, for example, it's defined as `__builtin_va_list`, a type that's implemented directly by the compiler. (It happens to have a size of 24 bytes on my system, but that's not particularly useful information -- except that it's not a pointer in that implementation).

Bottom line: The name `ap` is the conventional name for a `va_list` object, for no particular reason that we need to care about.